# The top bar color change when we change of view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a problem with my top bar, i initialize a color in my `MainViewController` with a function that is used in the `viewDidLoad` :

```
-(void)_initCustomTopBar
{
NSLog(@"init");
UIColor *barColour = [UIColor colorWithRed:22.0f/255.0f green:61.0f/255.0f blue:121.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIView *colourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, -20.f, 320.f, 64.f)];
colourView.opaque = NO;
colourView.alpha = .7f;
//colourView.backgroundColor = barColour;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = barColour;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer insertSublayer:colourView.layer atIndex:1];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont
                                                                       fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:20], NSFontAttributeName,
                            [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];


self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes;
}
```

But when i change of view, the top bar became gray and when i click on return the `MainViewController` top bar became gray too.
Have an idea for why it became gray ? And how correct that ?

Comment: call the method in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: show your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: No it is like before.

Comment: in my `viewDidLoad` , i call `[self _initCustomTopBar]`

Comment: "change of view" in the sense you are pushing a view controller?

Comment: This probably has everything to do with the view you are moving to - can you share it's code / check its setup in the storyboard if applicable ?

Comment: i have my MainViewController, i click on a button and i switch of view controller, when i back on the first page the top bar have change.

Comment: Right, but I think this behaviour is coming from something in the view controller you are moving to.

Comment: There must be some other code running somewhere that is changing the color of bar. Share your storyboard screenshot and also both of your view controller's  code.

Answer (score 0):

Call this _initCustomTopBar in your viewWillAppear method

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[self _initCustomTopBar];

}
```

Comment: I have do that, but there is the same problem

Comment: Can you please tell me what are you actually doing , means what do you meant by change of view ?

Comment: I mean that i have some viewControllers, and when i switch of view controller, the top bar is gray and when i back on the first page the color of the top bar is gray too (i have initialized with a blue color)